# Email Attachments using php mail() function - Working for gmail but attachments are of null size (0 bytes) for yahoo

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, ymail

I am sending email with attachments using php mail() function.

It is working for gmail but attachments are of null size (0 bytes) for yahoo.

Here is attachment code that I have used :

```
                $xMessage .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $xMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
                $xMessage .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

                $xMessage .= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n";

                $xMessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename("uploads/attachment_file/".$file['attachment_name'])."\"\r\n";

                $xMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

                $xMessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename("uploads/attachment_file/".$file['attachment_name'])."\"\r\n";

                $content = file_get_contents("uploads/attachment_file/".$file['attachment_name']);

                $xMessage.= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

                $xMessage .= "\r\n\r\n";
```

What should I do to get attachments in yahoo also?

Answer (score -1):

change /r/n to

```
$eol = PHP_EOL;
```

and change

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename("uploads/attachment_file/".$file['attachment_name'])."\"\r\n";
```

to

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename("uploads/attachment_file/".$file['attachment_name']).$eol.$eol;
```